# Homestead not working properly

Tags: macos, homestead

I have installed vagrant on my machine.  I have homestead installed both globally and in my project.

When I run `vagrant up` it does not work, I am unable to access the url in my browser, it comes up with a blank screen.

So I searched online and found a solution that allowed me to use `homestead up` by editing my ~/bash_profile and adding the following code:

```
function homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Workspace/homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

Now when I navigate to my project director and run homestead up it works I am able to access the site via the url in my browser however I encountered another issue, it seemed to be loading from the global homestead.yaml file instead of my project's homestead.yaml file.

When I removed the site from my global homestead.yaml file and put it in my project's homestead.yaml file I kept getting no

> input file specified

This is my project's **homestead.yaml** file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: blog
name: blog
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "~/Workspace/blog"
      to: "/home/vagrant/workspace/blog"

sites:
    - map: blog.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/workspace/blog/public"

databases:
    - blog

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And this is my global **homestead.yaml** file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/Laravel/public

databases:
    - blog

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to flag --provision after you edited your .yaml file, so

```
homestead up --provision
```

OR

```
homestead reload --provision
```

Furthermore in your global Homestead.yaml you're syncing also the Homestead folder with the virtual box, that doesn't make much sense.

I would leave that apart and change it's path to ~/Homestead/ so your ~/Workspace/ will contain only the projects.

so change your bash profile accordingly, and change your Homestead.yaml file to reflect this (if you want to run multiple projects on the same box you won't need "projet" yaml file, but just the hometead global yaml file):

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Workspace
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/Laravel/public
    - map: blog.app
      to: /home/vagrant/workspace/blog/public
```

Hope this help

Cheers